# Raycast hit error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, raycasting

I have a question, when I write this to play a sound when the player is under the distance from 4 unity meter and press "e", but it gives me an error that `hit` can't convert to `float`. What should I do now?

```
public AudioSource sound;

public int rayLength = 4;
public GameObject doorText;
RaycastHit hit;

void Update()
{
    var fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);

    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, hit, rayLength))
    {
        if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Boxen")
        {
            doorText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            if (Input.GetKeyDown("e")) //or Input.GetKeyDown("e")    Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")
            {
                sound.Play();
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        doorText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing an `out` keyword on that call

```
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, out hit, rayLength)) {
```

It allows the method to write into the `hit` argument. Without it C# will not recognize the desired overload and point you to the closest available one, in this case, where the third argument is a float.